# Variable parser for the Hack programming language

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parsing

I am optimizing the variable parser for [my programming language](http://code.google.com/p/hack-programming-language/), and also trying to make it more readable and concise (precedence: readable and concise > efficient). What is the best way to improve this code and make the best out of each line, and make it easier to understand for contributors?

```
namespace pro_compiler
{
    /* Handles all the variable declarations */
    public class VarParser : Parser
    {
        public VarParser( )
            : base()
        {    
        }

        public string Parse(ref string line)
        {
            CheckVariable(ref line);
            return line;
        }

        public void CheckVariable(ref string line)
        {
            /* Check current line for the "var" keyword */
            if (line.StartsWith("var"))
            {
                string decl = line;       
                decl += ';';
                line = decl;
                CheckFunctions(ref line);
            }    
        }

        /* check if the var declaration contains any functions
         * e.g var input = readln; */
        public string CheckFunctions(ref string line)
        {
            var words = line.Split(' '); //check wether each word is a function
            line = ""; // clear the current line

            foreach (var word in words)
            {               
                string w = word.Trim(); //trim all leading and trailing spaces.

                foreach(var pair in FuncTable.Instance.NormSet)
                {
                    if (w.StartsWith(pair.Key)) // if the word is a function 
                    {
                        w = w.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value + "( )"); // replace it with the C# equivalent
                    }
                }

                w = ((w == words[0]) ? "" : " ") + w; // reinsert trailing and leading spaces
                line += w; // add the words back to the current line
            }

            return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have used a lot of the C# standard library methods, since I figured that the people who wrote those have 10 times more skills than me and wrote them as efficiently as possible. Is this good? Or is it better to implement my own string functions?

Comment: I'd use a parser generator instead of writing your own from scratch.  It will be a lot easier to define and maintain your grammar and code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## A few observations...

### General

- It would be great if you could include a syntax snippets of how a line in your programming language would look so we can test our solutions against the expected output. I had to go to your Google Code project and search for an actual syntax example in your source files
- Your parsing functionality is still very rudimentary. (I didn't change that.) It can't yet handle function arguments and it doesn't work if there are no spaces in between words. Also, if there are spaces in front of the variable declaration, the function will not get translated at all  (this I fixed)
- It's usually advisable to stick with library functions and *not* to reinvent the wheel, *especially* since you have stated that readability trumps efficiency in your scenario. .NET's string functions are mostly fine
- There's no need to explicitly specify the default constructor as it (along with it's call to the argument-less constructor of `Parser`) will be automatically generated by the compiler. Leaving it out means one less thing for your readers and contributors to worry about

### Naming issues

- According to the comment just above the class definition, `VarParser handles all the variable declarations`. Although this makes sense, I'd suggest you ponder on finding a more *descriptive* name, such as `VariableDeclarationParser` or at least `VariableParser`
- The function name `CheckVariable` is lacking at best, or misinformation at worst. It tells us it is "checking a variable" but in reality it isn't - it's checking if the current line *contains a variable and, if it does, it will process the line - otherwise it will do nothing*. An adequate name for that would be `ParseLineIfItContainsAVariableDeclaration`. Of course we **don't** use that, but rather we realize that the function needs to be split up to separate the check from the processing, so we choose two names for our new functions:

  - `ContainsVariableDeclaration(string line)` will return a `bool` indicating if we should process the line
  - `ParseLine(string line)` will return a string containing the parsed line
- `FuncTable` is a very vague name for your Singleton containing the (also vague) `NormSet` - consider something like `HackToCSharpMapper` (or just `LanguageMapper`) and `FunctionMappings` or something along those lines instead of `NormSet`
- `CheckFunctions` *doesn't **check** anything*, rather it seems to parse functions. Therefore, name it `ParseFunctionsIn(string line)`
- I'm not saying you should choose the exact names I recommended, just try to think of the name that captures what the function does best and don't imply a function is doing something it doesn't do
- **Naming is important** because it forces us to define what a given function, variable or class *should* do. When we end up with long names (see example above), we know that our code isn't well-structured and needs to be changed so that we follow the principles of OOP.

> A function should do **one thing**. It should do it **well**. It should do it **only.**
>               — Robert C. Martin in [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)
>
> ### Comments

Almost all of your comments can be made obsolete by choosing proper names and generally making the code as expressive as possible. IMHO, we should avoid comments that tell us *what* a particular statement does, rather we should use them **only** to clarify **why** we have made an unusal decision.
Or, to put it like [Uncle Bob](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882), *I view every comment I write as a **failure** to express myself in code*.
So I deleted most of your comments from the refactored version below because the names now stand for themselves, without the need for further clarification.

### Dangerous and unusual things

- Are you sure there won't be any whitespace before the `var` keyword? I've added a call to `String.TrimStart()` to make sure we don't stumble over this edge case
- In your class, I see **absolutely no reason** to pass the `line` parameter *by reference*. This should be avoided because it makes your code more unpredictable - one can no longer be sure whether the function has a side effect on the input parameter

  - `CheckFunctions` returns a string, but the return value is never used because you rely on the `ref` parameter - be consistent!
- Why are `CheckVariable` and `CheckFunctions` `public`? Too me, it looks like they *should only ever be accessed from within that class*
- What if someone passes in a line that doesn't contain a variable declaration? At the moment, there will be no warning at all, the result will just be the same as the input - I suggest changing your program to throw an `ArgumentException` if it is not passed a valid declaration

### Loops

- Your nested `foreach` loop is unnecessary and bad for performance because it loops over all possibilities. As further investigation of the rest of your source code on Google Code shows, `FuncTable.Instance.NormSet` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` and therefore suitable for **fast access by key**.
- Note that in your original code, you kept going through further possible function matches *even after you have already replaced the current word with it's C# function!*

After quite a bit of refactoring, we arrive at the below solution. If anything needs to be clarified, go ahead and ask.

## Refactored example

All methods could have been made static, however I suspect you will change the base class - to which VariableDeclarationParser has **no dependency** at the moment - to a more useful one that provides a `virtual Parse()` method that can be overridden.

```
public class VariableDeclarationParser : Parser
{
    public string Parse(string line)
    {
        if (ContainsVariableDeclaration(line))
        {
            return ParseLine(line);
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid declaration: " + line);
    }

    private bool ContainsVariableDeclaration(string line)
    {
        return line.TrimStart().StartsWith("var");
    }

    private string ParseLine(string line)
    {
        string parsedLine = string.Empty;
        foreach (string word in line.Split(' '))
        {
            parsedLine += GetFunctionOrVariable(word);
        }
        return parsedLine.TrimEnd() + ";";
    }

    private string GetFunctionOrVariable(string candidate)
    {
        string key = candidate.Trim();
        var mappings = HackToCSharpMapper.Instance.FunctionMappings;
        if (mappings.ContainsKey(key)) return mappings[key] + "() ";
        return candidate + " ";
    }
}
```

If you're into LINQ, consider this alternative `ParseLine` function. It's more concise, but it sacrifices some readability - I think the above `foreach` is the better solution.

```
private string ParseLine(string line)
{
    string parsedLine = line.Split(' ').Aggregate(
        string.Empty, (parsed, word) => parsed + GetFunctionOrVariable(word));
    return parsedLine.TrimEnd() + ";";
}
```

Comment: +1, Thank You. Wish I could upvote this answer a million times.

Comment: Great answer. As an alternative to making the Parse method virtual, you might consider putting abstract ShouldParseLine (replaces ContainsVariableDeclaration) and ParseLine methods on the Parser base class.  Then, implement the Parse method  as a non-virtual method also on the Parser base class.  This would enforce all classes derived from the Parser class to follow the same implementation pattern.